# Is "huge" slightly informal?

Tags: word-choice, formality

Is "huge" slightly informal?

In the following sentence,

> First, some people insist that Japan doesn’t need to adopt [an]
>   austerity policy because it has a huge amount of assets at home and
>   abroad.

I felt the word "huge" was inappropriate, thinking that it was too informal for this context. (Whereas if someone said "OMG, I have a bloody huge hangover", "huge" wouldn't be too informal)

However, meaning 1 of huge in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huge) and [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/huge?s=t&ld=1089) don't describe it as slangy or informal.

Am I mistaken in thinking that it's informal? Perhaps I only think it's informal because it's a popular word in informal speech because you can lengthen the "u".

Comment: I chuckled at the _lengthened 'u'_ part of your question. In other words, "huge" is not informal, but "huuuuuuuuuge" is. I'd concur with that :^)

Comment: 'Prodigious' is certainly formal but doesn't collocate well here either. I'd say 'incredible assets'.

Answer (score 4):

I don't regard "it has a huge amount of assets" as informal, but I do regard it as bad writing, and would instead say "it has huge assets".  Note, besides not regarding it as informal, I also don't regard it as formal, nor would I regard it as formal if a synonym such as *major, substantial, significant* were substituted. All of those quantities are quite indefinite, and I think a formal statement (in sense of official statement) should give more-precise information about assets or debt.

Comment: Just my opinion, but changing "huge amount of assets" to "substantial assets" would be a huge improvement to the original. +1

Comment: I don't think the sentence Andrew Grimm cited could be regarded as a formal or official statement. However, I agree that that 'huge assets' is too indefinite. 'Huge assets' are of little significance if they are offset by 'huge liabilities'. But perhaps this was discussed subsequently in the source.

Comment: Isn't "assets" a mass noun in this context?

Answer (score 0):

It’s probably neither here nor there, but [this Google N-Gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great+amount+of%2Chuge+amount+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) makes me wonder whether its perceived slanginess is about its comparative newness:

[image]

Comment: It's not a new word. It comes from 'Middle English' which is at least 500 years old.

Comment: a1275   *The Proverbs of Ælfred* 709 in *An Old English Miscellany* 138   Þuru þis lore and genteleri he amendit **huge** companie. *[By this teaching and [his] noble character he put things right for a huge group/number of people.]*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's informal. The informal part of it depends on the way you intonate it. If you intoned it as a long *u*, it would sound funny and I think informal. But in writing it wouldn't make that big of a difference unless you were writing a play script.

Answer (score 0):

As a real-life example: In a first draft I described my client's customers as ranging from 'monster manufacturers with a national footprint' down to 'mom-and-pop doughnut shops'. One faction of reviewers objected to 'monster' as too slangy, another faction defended it as residing in the same register as 'mom-and-pop' (they didn't use those terms, but that's what they meant). In the end, the two factions compromised on 'huge'.

Answer (score 0):

*Huge* does not seem informal but it does seem a bit emotive. I seems to impart the opinion of the speaker in the example given.

Answer (score 0):

## My advice

My English teacher told me that the word: `huge` is informal. My assignment was to write a formal E-mail with a formal letter/report as attachment. I used huge everywhere, luckily I still got a high grade because she is a friendly teacher. Your teacher or person who grades your assignment might not let you off the hook that easily as mine.

She gave me alternative examples to use instead of `huge`:
E.g. a `huge` project = a `sizable`/`long`/`complicated`/`lengthy` project

It depends if you're writing something as an assignment for school or when you're just writing something formal to business partners or something. I don't think it's a big deal in the real world, but at school teachers might think otherwise. My advice would be: If it's formal writing exercise, assignment or exam for school, avoid the word `huge`, especially in assignments whereby you're writing something formal or business-related.

### British English considers it informal

This answer also depends on where you live and what kind of English you get thought and what your school assignment wants you to use. In British English `huge` is an informal word, see Oxford Learner's Dictionaries: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/huge (under 2)

Comment: While I tend to agree that 'huge' is less formal than say 'extensive' (and not as informal as 'monster'), ELU appreciates answers with linked references to supporting authorities. Do any dictionaries add the 'informal' caveat?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The thing is I didn't really understand why `huge` was seen as informal. Outside of my school nobody cares. A lot of supposedly `informal` words became everyday use. I worked for approximately 5 years as a web developer, sysadmin and tech support and I have seen the word `huge` used in all forms of communications.

I think a lot of schools are very outdated with what's formal and what's not and often don't reflect how society currently uses words and phrases. That's why my advice is based on: Is it for school? Avoid it. And anything else, it's fine.

Comment: Also my school is called: Amsterdam University of Applied Sciences
And what I meant by avoid it when it's for school, I meant when it's an writing exercise. Outside that everybody uses `huge`. You might even call that hypocritical when it's not allowed in a writing exercise. The inconsistencies I often see in a lot of rules and policies is a lot and most of the times even silly.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/huge) under US usages labels the 'popular / important' sense (also purloining 'big' and 'massive') as [informal], but not the more usual ones. I'd say it's pretty complex; 'a huge majority' sounds more natural to me than 'a huge set of paintings'.

Comment: Indeed. I live in The Netherlands, Europe and we also use British English. Therefore my university might be more strict and formal than what's really necessary.

I use Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries and whatnot, but I fully agree with you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also, please upvote my answer if you think it's alright :)

Comment: As said above, ELU appreciates answers with linked references to supporting authorities.  I found the Collins entries showing that their usage panel doesn't consider 'huge' to be informal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/huge?q=huge

Oxford says it's informal and I live in The Netherlands, Europe and we get thought British English. So it depends. In American English it's not informal but it's in British English.

Comment: Also, Oxford is the dictionary authority of the British English. What they say goes basically. In America that might be Merriam-Webster

Comment: No; OALD like Collins says that the 'popular / important' sense is informal, not adding this for the more usual sense/s, which it thus classes as not informal. And OALD and OED are totally different works. Though I'd be surprised if OED has the caveat for the 'huge stockpiles' sense. Your answer needs adjusting now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I literally sent you the link, here look again: oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/huge?q=huge. Okay, I will also check a hard copy in my house.

Comment: (1) The linked article has the [informal] register caveat *for the 'very successful' sense only*. // (2) OED is an entirely different dictionary, not the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary you link to. Not an abridged/older version.

Answer (score -1):

Huge means large -- physically. Huge house, wave. If you want to say significant, important or a lot (quantity) then say THAT. It is not that it is informal or formal so much that it is inaccurate.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/huge)  gives as examples of usage: *Your help made a huge difference* and *a dancer of huge talent*.

Comment: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/huge) has: '**huge** [adjective]: extremely large in size or amount:
• They live in a huge house. / • The costs involved in building a spacecraft are huge. / • A huge number of people attended.'